# Windows 7 64-bit installation freezes after a while during the setup

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, freeze

I have Windows 7 32-bit on my computer. Because I have 5GB of RAM (Kingston) on my Asus M2N motherboard and only 3GB were able to be used, I bought Windows 7 64-bit and installed it. It loads the wizard, but after a while, it freezes, and I have to force reboot. It first crashed while unzipping Windows 7 files, but if I wait a while on the terms page for example, it can crash before, which make me think that it is a matter of time. I remember I had the same issue while booting on Ubuntu 64-bit, it crashed randomly but not load completely. No beep or other messages.

**Configuration:**

- Software

  - OS (before) Windows 7 Professional 32-bit
  - New OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
  - Antivirus: Avast (BIOS verification?)
  - BIOS;  03/27/2008 - v08.00.12
- Hardware

  - Motherboard: Asus M2N
  - Processor: AMD Athlon 64 dual core 2.6 GHz
  - Memory: 5120MB ((2 + 2) + (1))

NOTES  I ran a memory test using openSUSE CD, though I have not finished it, it ran.

**EDIT**: I tried not to run the setup but wait, and I get a BSOD

A problem... TL;DW

```
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
```

If it is... TL;DW

```
***STOP: 0x0000000A (0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000001, 0xFFFFF8001A49ED1F)
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, it was because of the memory : I had 2 x 2gb + 1 x 1gb, and a slot alone is not a good idea,  so i removed the 1gb slot and it worked.

Comment: uhm, that **should** not be a problem. A single DIMM in a dual channel capable motherboard should just work. And just because it is not displayed as a recommended configuration on page 2-11 of [the manual(http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM2/m2n/e2753_m2n.pdf) does not mean that you can not use it. Are you sure that the 1GB DIMM is working fine and that it has the appropriate timings to match the other DIMMs?